# How would to assign exclusive right of a file to a process in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio to develop a windows form application in c++ to detect certain anomalies and log it.

The log file that I am intending to create will be of a common format such as .txt. I do not want users of the computer to modify this file that is I want only my program to modify it( I want users to read this file not modify it).

Is there any way to achieve this??

Comment: No, of course not. If it's on the user's computer, they can access it. What would it hurt if they do?

Comment: log all into memory and then send across network to your secret server

Comment: *"I do not want users of the computer to access this file"*  Why not?

Comment: another possibility is to ask user about his native language and then encode file in other, i.e. user says english -> so encode in japaneese, I am joking of course

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hide the content from other users then encrypt the file or use a binary format that only your program will be able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the file resides on a publicly accessible area in the file system, then other users will be able to access it.

You can put the file in a specific user's `Documents` area, which might go some way to protecting the file from other users of that machine, but not from administrators.

You could even set the file attributes to "hidden" or something along those lines, to further make it hard for people to find it. But a complete access block is difficult (if not impossible).

After all this, you can also use NirMH's method to ensure that even if someone finds and attempts to read the file, then the encryption should make it difficult to crack it open. A binary format can still be read with a hex editor, if someone is really keen to read your file.